# protractor clickanddrug on canvas

Tags: canvas, drag-and-drop, protractor, pageobjects

I need to automate a signature on a canvas. When I used Cucumber I used canvas.click_and_drop_by and now when I try to perform it using protractor I read that I have to use the action sequence.
How do I do it if I'm using Page-Objects?

this is the canvas:

```html
<canvas class="pad float-left" height="100" width="290" title=""></canvas>
```

this is the page-object:

```js
function MyPage() {
    this.firstSignature = element(by.css('.pad')[0]);

    this.sign = function() {
        var offset = {x:30, y:30};
        browser.actions().
            mousemove(this.firstSignature, offset).
            mousedown().
            mousemove(45,45).
            mouseup().
            performAction();
    };
}

module.exports = MyPage;
```

How can I make this drag work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a special `dragAndDrop()` method:

```
browser.actions().dragAndDrop(this.firstSignature, {x: 45, y: 45}).perform();
```

Comment: I get this error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'findElementsOverride' of undefined

Comment: @user3742009 should not you have `firstSignature` defined as `element(by.css('.pad'));` instead of `element(by.css('.pad')[0]);`?

Comment: changed selector to element.all(by.css('.pad')).first();
now it works.